# Default WLAN password of Ruckus ZoneFlex 7352

Tags: router, wireless

I have a Ruckus ZoneFlex 7352 Access Point, Recently I have reset it. Somehow it is impossible to connect it to the laptop through LAN. And I don't know its default wifi Password. Its has SSID of Island-XXXXXX. I have tried entering mac address as password but it is not working. How to get the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that you need to configure the WAP first. Log into the config with `super`/ `sp-admin`.